# include Python.h error : initconfig.h not found

Tags: c++, c, python-3.x

```
#include <python3.8/Python.h>
```

I keep getting the error
/usr/include/python3.8/cpython/pystate.h:9:10: fatal error: cpython/initconfig.h: No such file or directory

```
9 | #include "cpython/initconfig.h"
```

Originally i just included Python.h, but that could not be found at all. I'm also running Void Linux, and already installed python3-devel if that makes a diffrence.

Comment: You cannot and should not include `Python.h` this way. You need to `#include <Python.h>` and pass an appropriate `-I` command line argument to the compiler, e.g. `-I/usr/include/python3.8`.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue40642

Answer (score 4):

try locate your Python.h:

```sh
gemfield@ThinkPad-X1C:~$ locate Python.h
/home/gemfield/anaconda3/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/home/gemfield/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.6-h0371630_2/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.8/Python.h
```

Then

```sh
g++ -I/usr/include/python3.8 ...
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained.